# Retrofit 2 Multipart sends only image instead of image and data

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm developing an app using Retrofit 2 for getting and sending data to API. When I try to upload an image with Multipart, API Logs that it hasn't got all data that I've sent to it. Here is my code:

Service interface method:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("photoUpload")
    Call<JsonObject> uploadPhoto(@Header("Accept") String acceptType,
                                     @Header("Authorization") String token, @Part("param1") okhttp3.RequestBody value1,
                                     @Part("param2") okhttp3.RequestBody value2,
                                     @Part("param3") okhttp3.RequestBody value3,
                                     @Part MultipartBody.Part photo);
```

Upload the image function:

```
service.uploadPhoto("application/json",
                            token, okhttp3.RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
                                    String.valueOf(value1)),
                            okhttp3.RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), value2),
                            okhttp3.RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),
                                    String.valueOf(value3),
                            getImage()).enqueue(...);
```

getImage() function:

```
private MultipartBody.Part getImage(File file){
        okhttp3.RequestBody body = okhttp3.RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), body);
    }
```